# How to fix 'cannot be loaded because running scripts is disable'

Tags: python-3.x, powershell, visual-studio-code

While trying to setting up a simple python code, I am stuck with error

> cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. For more information, see about_Execution_Policies

Have tried to open several scripts (simplest ones). Nothing works.

```python
import sys

print(sys.version)
print(sys.executable)

def greet(who_to_great):
    greeting = 'Hello, {}'.format(who_to_great)
    return greeting

print(greet('World'))
print(greet('Haider'))
```

I am following a tutorial and that's what should work. Am I missing something?

Comment: i have tried "Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned" in powershell as administrator and it worked.

Comment: The code you posted is Python, but the error message is from PowerShell. A Python script will not throw PowerShell errors, so there's clearly something you haven't told us yet.

Comment: i dont know as i am new to python coding. but as i finds out that there are some errors for which i have to use powershell.

Comment: source: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/2559

Comment: `activate.ps1` is a *PowerShell* script. The code you posted is *Python*. If you've for some reason put Python code in a PowerShell script and expect that to run: it won't.

Comment: Yes, you are right. i just figured it out that i accidentally choose powershell in vscode and thats where it all starts... but my problem was solved as i now can create env and do all sorts of work in there like i was doing before in vscode with python. if there is a difference then please do clear.